# Passing data to a different controller/model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to MVC in general, so this might sound very silly. However, I don't quite get how to connect my data in the following scenario:

I am creating a project where I have basically two tables

**Table 1**

```
pid  |  pname  |  etc
```

**Table 2**

```
id  |  pid  |  etc
```

Now, I have successfully implemented a controller where I populate a list with the data in `table 1` using "date range" as a parameter.

**URL 1**

```
/table1object?search=Search&endDate=2015-02-20&fromDate=2015-02-20
```

As the tables shown, each row in this `view` is connected to a certain row in `table 2`. So, for this I am generating a link which basically sends me to the details of the second controller by looping through the current `model`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details/" + @result.pId, "table2Object", null)
```

Now, my controller number 2 (Details) is only accepting an `id` to display that specific information of the `Table 2`.

**URL 2**

```
/table2object/Details/96
```

**The Question**

Since I am only passing this `id` to access the second controller, I am going to be able to see only one item at a time. What if I want to add a `previous` and `next` buttons to navigate through items in the second controller, but in the range established in the first controller? How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first way to do it without **respecting any best practices** is to save your search result (Controller1) inside a Session variable.

```
Session["CurrentResult"] = YourViewModelInController1 ;
```

and then in Controller 2

```
ActionResult Details(int id) 
{
   var prevViewModel = Session["CurrentResult"] ; 

   // Do what you want to find the prev and the next from prevViewModel
}
```

Of course you can't get the next and the prev if you access your DetailController without displaying table1.
And also, there will be many side effects. e.g :  when user make 2 search at once, ..

---

The second good and correct way to do it, is to re-execute a search to find the previous and the next on Controller 2 Details. Independently of the previous

```
ActionResult Details(int id) 
{
   // Do a real search to find the next and the previous
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. If I want to use the second way to do it. How can I look for prev and next without knowing the date range?

Comment: I feel bad for using the first way :(

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the idea how to pass values and work in a controller, i can give you a suggestion as below:

You can load your items in a list within a given date range first. Pass that list to 2nd controller And then traverse that list by clicking prev and next using a counter.

Hope this helps,
Thanks